# Configuring the max number of pods for a node on GKE

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud, cluster-computing, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm having some trouble configuring my deployments on GKE.

I want to decrease the default(110) number of pods allowed on a node and I can't do it through the console. I read that the max number of pods can be set by `kubelet --max-pods=<int32>` however I don't know how to do this with GKE.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be a value you can update, I only found this: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/quotas .

Comment: Seems a bit odd that you can't update that value, when the functionality is there in Kubernetes. Thank you for your input and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kubelet --max-pods=<int32>` approach you mentioned is actually deprecated as per the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/):

> This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the
>   Kubelet's --config flag. See
>   https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/
>   for more information.

However, in Google Kubernetes Engine, you can modify this by going to the `Developer Console > Kubernetes Engine > Clusters`, click on your cluster's name and click on `Add Node Pool` at the top. You'll be able to set a maximum number of pods per node for that new node pool.

Once done, you'll be able to deploy your services to specific node pools by following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools#deploying_services_to_specific_node_pools).

Comment: This seems to be in Beta if we take a look at the terraform ressource https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_node_pool.html , may explain why it's difficult to find informations about it in the google documentation for now;